# Oracle SQL Create Trigger to insert SEQ.nextval

Tags: oracle, sequence, database-trigger

I am creating a trigger to add same `SEQ.nextval` numbers to two fields such as follows:

```
SITE_NUM  SITE_NUM_COPY  Site_Name
346        346           XYZ
347        347           ABC
348        348           DEF
```

Whenever a new row is added through an application I want the `SITE_NUM` and `SITE_NUM_COPY` will be auto generated through the trigger.

This is what I have put together:

```
create or replace trigger SITE_TRIGGER
before insert or update on STRATEGY_SITES for each row
begin
if updating then
    if :new.SITE_NUM is null and :new.SITE_NUM_Copy is NULL then
        :new.SITE_NUM := :old.SITE_NUM
        and :old.SITE_NUM := :new.SITE_NUM_COPY;
    end if;
end if;
if inserting then
    :new.SITE_NUM := SITENUM_SEQ.nextval 
    and :new.SITE_NUM_COPY := SITENUM_SEQ.nextval;
end if;
end;
```

Getting the following error:

> Error(7,31): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following:
>        . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem     <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2    like4 likec between || indicator multiset member submultiset
>   The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue.

Answer (score 1):

The error is not very helpful but is stemming from you using `and` to, apparently, seperate two statements inside each `if` block. The statement terminator/separator is a semicolon.

It looks like you are trying to do this for the first one:

```
if updating then
    if :new.SITE_NUM is null and :new.SITE_NUM_Copy is NULL then
        :new.SITE_NUM := :old.SITE_NUM;
        :old.SITE_NUM := :new.SITE_NUM_COPY; -- illegal
    end if;
end if;
```

but you cannot change the `:old` values; it isn't clear what you expect to happen,  ot least as the value assigning must be null. You may just want to remove that line.

And for the second part:

```
if inserting then
    :new.SITE_NUM := SITENUM_SEQ.nextval;
    :new.SITE_NUM_COPY := SITENUM_SEQ.currval;
end if;
```

I've changed the second assignment to use `currval` because you said you wanted the same value for both columns. If you call `nextval` for both assignments they will get different values simce the sequnce will increment twice.